# How do I properly use the 0.0 in an if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

```
int main () {
    float hour, dec, Dec_Only, min2, sec;
    int res, r, min, whole, min3, sec2, sec3;
    
    printf ("Enter hours: ");
    scanf ("%f", &hour);
    
    //Displaying initial minutes
    min = hour * 60;
    printf ("%d minutes\n", min);

    if (hour == 0.0){
        res = min / 60;
        r = min % 60;
    
        printf("%02d : %02d : 00", res, r);
    }
    else {
        //Getting hours
        whole = (int)hour;
        dec = (hour - whole) * 100;
    
        //Getting minutes
        Dec_Only = hour - whole;
        min2 = Dec_Only * 60;
        min3 = (int)min2;
        
        //Getting seconds
        sec = min2 - min3;
        sec2 = sec * 60;
        sec3 = (int)sec2;
    
        printf ("%02d : %02d : %02d", whole, min3, sec3 );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Hello, Im new in C. My work is about converting the hours into a digital clock (where Im required to use Conditional Statements).
I added a conditional statement when the user_input only contains 1 decimal or more. My code works, however, when I enter the specific number 5.2, thats when the problem comes in.

Enter hours (user_input): 5.2
Output: 05 : 11 : 59

My desired output: 05: 12 : 00

PS: When I enter any other numbers it works.

Comment: probably because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). Use integers for hours, minutes, secs, etc,, even for fractional seconds.

Comment: Not the case with your code, but the equality comparison of floating point numbers is problematic in many other cases because floating point math is not exact. You might be expecting some calculation to result in `0.0`, but in fact it will result in something like `0.00000001112` (just made up number, this might not be representable as float/double), so the the comparison with `0.0` will be false.

Comment: Print the full value of `hour`: `printf("hour = %f\n", hour);` It is likely not exactly what you believe.

Comment: You might try using "double" in lieu of "float".

Comment: Woah thanks! I didnt know that theres a huge difference between double and float!

Comment: Aside from the math, something else is going on here. _"I added a conditional statement when the user_input only contains 1 decimal or more."_ No. Your posted code does not attempt to do this & has no way to do this. You would need to read the input as a string and parse it to count number of decimal places entered.

Comment: Using `double` will make a difference to precision, but you should also get the calculation into the integer world with rounding to the desired precision as soon as possible. For example, if rounding to the nearest second: `long long int seconds = round(hour * 60 * 60);`, or if rounding to the nearest millisecond `long long int millisecs = round(hour * 60 * 60 * 1000);`. Then you can use integer division and modulo operations to split the rounded integer value into whole numbers of hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds, for example.

Comment: Also, your `if (hour == 0.0)` makes no sense to me in this context. If hour == 0.0 then you will have min == 0 here will then set res and r to 0, no math needed.

Comment: Hint: never work in `float` unless there is a *specific reason* why you can't use `double`, the natural floating point type in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key problem is that entering `"5.2"` results in a `float` *near*, but nor exactly, 5.2. This is because `float` is encoded as a finite integer times a power-of-2 and cannot encode 5.2.  5.19999980926513671875 (which is 5,452,595 * 2<sup>-20</sup>) is commonly closest.

Instead of `min = hour * 60`, which assigns a *truncated* value to `min`, use `min = lroundf(hour * 60);` (from `<math.h>`) to *round* the `float` product to the nearest `long`.

Rest of code should not use `hours` or floating-point math again.  Just use integer math.

---

Even better: convert `hours` into a whole number of seconds first.

```
    #define SEC_PER_HOUR_FP (60.0 * 60) 
    long total = lround(hour * SEC_PER_HOUR_FP);
    int s = total%60;
    total /= 60;
    int m = total%60;
    total /= 60;
    long h = total;
    printf ("%02ld : %02d : %02d", h, m, s);
```

Answer (score 2):

The float vs double stuff mentioned in the comments is just masking the problem. The real issue is that "0.2" *cannot* be exactly represented in binary floating point. Much like how 1/3 can't be represented using a finite expansion in base 10 (0.333...), 2/10 is 0.001100110011... in base 2.  So you need an infinite number of bits to store 0.2 exactly, and since you don't have that, you get rounding errors whenever you do arithmetic on it.

Using double increases the number of bits you have, and might decrease the rounding error by enough that you get the right answer in this *particular* case, but it doesn't eliminate it. Some amount of rounding error has already happened as soon as you read the number in: `hour` is not 5.2; it's 5.19999980926513671875. (If you used float, there would be even more initial error.)

What you want to do is convert to an integral representation as soon as possible to avoid accumulating more rounding error.
`unsigned long seconds = round(hour * 60.0 * 60.0);` (round is in math.h).
If you just assign `hour * 60.0 * 60.0` to seconds, it'll truncate instead of rounding: 18719.999313354492187 becomes 18719 instead of 18720: that's where your missing second comes from. `round` rounds it to the *nearest* integer instead of truncating to the next lowest.  Once you've got seconds as an unsigned long, all your arithmetic will be integer division (which truncates to just the amount that divided evenly) and modulo (the remainder), which give results that can be *exactly* represented by the machine.

Eventually, you'll want to read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). If you just started, it might be a bit above your level, but give it a shot and if you don't understand it, come back and try again after you've got a bit more experience.

(Also, include newlines in those printf calls. I'm guessing you're using an IDE that automatically puts a newline after its output, but if you run this on the command line, that newline will be missing.)

Comment: As an aside, the difference between the `lround` that chux used and the `round` that I used is whether the conversion to long/unsigned long happens inside the function or implicitly when you assign to an integral variable. Either will work as long as you don't enter any values greater than 68 years.  After that point, round is better if your system has 32 bit longs and lround is better for 64 bit longs (although with 64 bit longs, the difference only shows up once the time is greater than 20 million years).

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here are ones I firmly agree with. I'm just chipping in with a small diversion.

**Butterfly Effect**

This is exactly the kind of thing that Edward Lorenz ran into in the early days of computational weather forecasting (actually, the work was related to early attempts at weather control).

He famously stopped a run part way through, printed out the results. Restarting the run the next day, despite having typed in the numbers as printed, the sim produced a very different result to its previous output. This caused a lot of confusion. It turned out to be due to the kind of problem represented in the other answers here, coupled with some modest rounding effects: just because a number printed out as 0.2, does not mean that was the value as represented in the machine's memory.

The result is now what we call the "Butterfly Effect", that very small differences in input in some systems (such as can have very large impacts on the course of subsequent events. The result was that they knew as a result that weather forecasting could never, ever be totally accurate (and therefore the results of weather control impossible to predict).

**Financial Calcs**

As a further diversion, the kind of effect is an issue in financial systems. If you're performing computations involving $billions (e.g.a currency conversion), people get a bit upset if the answer is a few cent out (which it will be if you use even double precision arithmetic). Seems disproportionate, but there you go.

There are libraries for carrying out decimal arithmetic - i.e. as if you were doing the calculation as taught at school on paper - which work to arbitrary precisions. IBM's mainframe Power processor family even has a hardware coprocessor for this kind of arithmetic, to speed it up. This is one of the reasons why mainframes still rule in certain circles; Intel / AMD don't have such coprocessors.

Comment: Note: [C2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C23_(C_standard_revision)) is expected to optional support decimal floating point types.

Comment: Of course, decimal arithmetic *also* has numbers that can't be represented exactly (e.g., 1/3, 1/7, π). It's just that we're used to that, so we aren't surprised by the rounding errors you get on those, whereas we *are* surprised when we get rounding error for 1/10.